# How to use firebase authentication user data after the page is redirected to another page (dashboard)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

after sign in with email and password using firebase authentication , the page is redirected to user dashboard , how can i use the user credntials in that dashboard after the page is redirected.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
                      .then(cred => {
                          console.log(cred.user);

                          window.location='dashboard.html'
                         }).catch(err => {
                        this.feedback=err.message;
                      })
```

the data is stored in cloud firestore using the given command :-

```
 firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
                        .then(cred => {
                            return db.collection('students').doc(cred.user.uid).set({
                                name: this.name,
                                email: this.email
                            });


                    }).then(() => {
                        this.feedback='User registered, please login.';
                        window.location='login.html' ;
                    })
                    .catch(err => {

                        this.feedback=err.message;
                        });
```

i want to use the  store  details on the index of  user uid in the database
and display it on the user dashboard

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
                      if (user) {
                        console.log(user.email);
                        window.location= 'dashboard.html'
                        console.log(user.email);
                        this.name = user.displayName ;
                        this.email =user.email;
                      }

                  })
```

Comment: Have you tried using `localStorage`? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i am new to all of these, for now i haven't tried anything

Comment: When asking a Stack Overflow question, it is best to have actually tried to solve the issue by yourself. Otherwise, it feels like we're doing your work for you as opposed to helping you in places where you're truly stuck.

Comment: sorry i mean i have tried using Current user but when the login page is redirected to different page the user is logged out or null. So i am stuck at how the user is not logged out for different urls

Comment: Assuming the `onAuthStateChanged` code you added to your question is in the dashboard file, what logging output does it show after you load the dashboard. Please copy/paste the exact output from the JavaScript console of your browser into your question.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks i was able to retain the user credentials on the next url , it was just the issue of my syntax

Answer (score 0):

To get the user on the new page, use an `onAuthStateChange` listener as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

> ```
> firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
>   if (user) {
>     // User is signed in.
>   } else {
>     // No user is signed in.
>   }
> });
> ```

In the `else` block, you'd typically redirect back to the login page. Since Firebase Authentication automatically refreshes its short-lived ID tokens, having the above code in the dashboard page also means that the user can safely bookmark this dashboard page's URL and return to it later.

Comment: i have the used the same onAuthStateChange listener, but whenever the page redirects to the dashboard after login, the login user credentials are shown as null in the console. (the user gets signout everytime the page redirects).

Comment: The code you shared doesn't show an `onAuthStateChanged` listener so it'll be impossible to say why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: i have edited the code and added ```onAuthStateChanged ``` listener. So, i hope if now you can help.